# Is singleton bean load same object for different reference, although there is one reference declared in xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, xml-configuration

I have the `ITest` interface and the `ClassA` class:

```
interface ITest {}
class ClassA implements ITest {}
```

The XML configuration:

```
<bean id="objectA" class= "ClassA" />
```

---

```
class Test {

       ITest objectB;

}
```

Although there is no bean declared in the XML file for reference `objectB` but it has `ClassA` object. Is it because it's singleton and `objectA` reference declared?

Comment: In Spring by default all bean declarations are Singleton. This works because of Spring Autowiring By Type. Do read about different ways of spring Autowiring  and the order in which it is done

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would trigger Spring to wire `objectA` to `Test.objectB`, so `objectB` will be `null` if you don't set it manually.

Comment: @daniu but its loading object of ClassA.